# Read input twice on the same line (without line break) using Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell

I was trying to read user input twice on the same line from a bash script. It's not very useful at all, but it's pretty and I'm trying to achieve this.

**The relevant part of my code looks like that:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FROM_YEAR=2015
TO_YEAR=2017
read -e -p "Backup from " -i "${FROM_YEAR}" FROM_YEAR
read -e -p " to "         -i "${TO_YEAR}"   TO_YEAR
```

**With this code I get the following:**

```
Backup from 2015 *press enter*
 to 2017
```

**But I would like output like this:**

```
Backup from 2015 *press enter* to 2017
```

Of course, I want an output without the marking (`*press enter*` ).

---

#### How can I achieve that with bash script?

Thank you :)

Comment: Pressing Enter to answer a prompt automatically goes to the next line. `bash` is not a form-filling application.

Comment: There's no way to workaround this?

Comment: Use a tool for full-screen input, instead of the `read` built-in.

Answer (score 1):

There are always workarounds, but they are not always portable.  There's a good chance this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

FROM_YEAR=2015
TO_YEAR=2017
read -e -p "Backup from " -i "${FROM_YEAR}" FROM_YEAR 
printf '\033[1A\033[16C'
read -e -p " to " -i "${TO_YEAR}" TO_YEAR
```

Note that this is a terrible hack, and if FROM_YEAR does not have exactly 4 digits after you edit it, the result will not be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM_YEAR=2015 TO_YEAR=2017
read -p "Backup from ${FROM_YEAR} to ${TO_YEAR}: " FROM_YEAR TO_YEAR
echo $FROM_YEAR $TO_YEAR
```

Output, if the user enters "3 4":

```
Backup from 2015 to 2017: 3 4
3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, I guess, `clear` the screen before the initial display, then `clear` the screen again after the user presses [Enter] so that you can re-display things where you want them.

I have bash scripts with menus that work like that.  You have to re-display everything, but for simple needs it does the job (if you do not mind clearing the screen, of course).